# WPF: Can't drop dragged data onto an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, itemscontrol

I have the following XAML:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="OverViewContainer" AllowDrop="True">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <uicommon:Toolbar DataContext="{Binding Commands}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DocumentElements}"
                  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource DocumentElementsItemTemplate}" />
</DockPanel>
```

When I drag data onto this panel, the mouse cursor shows a drop is allowed on all the child items, but on any empty space, the cursor shows that dropping is disabled. If I set `AllowDrop` to false, I can't drop onto the child items anymore, so the flag DOES have an effect. I would like to drop data into the margins between the items in the `ItemsControl`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that your DockPanel is not performing hit testing - since it has no background.

The solution? Add a Background="Transparent" attribute to the <DockPanel> tag.

Comment: Excellent, it also works if you just have an ItemsControl (not inside DockPanel). Also, that is a HORRIBLE behaviour :-(